# How to render the kendo-vue-ui chart after the data is fetched from the backend

Tags: vuejs2, kendo-ui

I am using a `kendo-charts-vue-wrapper` component which should display the chart, by fetching up the value from the API.

The code below shows a part of the implementation of the kendo-charts.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import $ from 'jquery';
import '@progress/kendo-ui';
import { Chart, ChartSeriesItem, SotckChart, Sparkline, SparklineSeriesItem, ChartInstaller } from '@progress/kendo-charts-vue-wrapper';
import JSZip from 'jszip';

Vue.use(ChartInstaller);

new Vue({
    el: "#vueapp",
    beforeMount(){
      this.getData();
    },
    methods:{
      getData(){
        //make the API call here.
        this.xlabel = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003];
        this.ylabel = [200, 450, 300, 125];
      }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            series: [{
                name: 'Example Series',
                data: this.ylabel //get value fetching from the api
            }],
            categories: this.xlabel //get value fetching from the api
        }
    }
})
```

Templates:

```
<div id="vueapp" class="vue-app">
    <kendo-chart :title-text="'Kendo Chart Example'"
                 :series="series"
                 :category-axis-categories="categories"
                 :theme="'sass'">
    </kendo-chart>
</div>
```

Here is the implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ffek5q

In this example, I wanted to get the data from the backend using the API call and bind the value to the `series` and `categories`

But when the template renders the data is not fetched through the API and the template is not able to show the chart with the proper data.

What is the appropriate way to render the template after fetching al the proper value from the backend? What could be the work-around for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved, these issues:

At first, I initialize the `series` and `categories` as empty array. And then, after getting the data from `getData`, set the value of series and categories.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import $ from 'jquery';
import '@progress/kendo-ui';
import { Chart, ChartSeriesItem, SotckChart, Sparkline, SparklineSeriesItem, ChartInstaller } from '@progress/kendo-charts-vue-wrapper';
import JSZip from 'jszip';

Vue.use(ChartInstaller);

new Vue({
    el: "#vueapp",
    beforeMount(){
      this.getData();
    },
    methods:{
      getData(){
        //make the API call here.
        this.categories = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003];
        this.series =  [{
                name: 'Example Series',
                data: [200, 450, 300, 125] //get value fetching from the api
            }];
      }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            series: [],
            categories: []//get value fetching from the api
        }
    }
})
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ffek5q-adue4f?file=index.js